Spring Data Elasticsearch throws error when Elasticsearch service is not started
Setting @Document(indexName = "person", createIndex = true) without starting the Elasticsearch service on the machine, the Spring Boot project fails to start and reports the following error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sourceItemESRepository' defined in com.sage.server.feature.source.database.repository.SourceItemESRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:221) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:571) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:571) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:536) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:79) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused: getsockopt
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:110) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:64) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:73) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.doExists(IndicesTemplate.java:177) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.exists(IndicesTemplate.java:169) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:85) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:208) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused: getsockopt
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:63) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: getsockopt
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:930) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.10.4.jar:8.10.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:300) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.10.4.jar:8.10.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.10.4.jar:8.10.4]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientHttpClient.performRequest(RestClientHttpClient.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.10.4.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.ElasticsearchTransportBase.performRequest(ElasticsearchTransportBase.java:137) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.10.4.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.ElasticsearchIndicesClient.exists(ElasticsearchIndicesClient.java:655) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.10.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.lambda$doExists$2(IndicesTemplate.java:177) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:71) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: getsockopt
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:973) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]


I checked the approach of using @Lazy, but that doesn't work for my situation because my other Beans need to depend on ElasticsearchRepository. Unless I change the code structure and encapsulate another layer.
Currently I have to manually change the value of createIndex before running the springboot application to accommodate Elasticsearch.
Is there any way to prevent Spring Data Elasticsearch throwing an error, or to make Spring Boot catch the error and continue to start?
Here is the code I used:
@Repository
interface SourceItemESRepository : ElasticsearchRepository<SourceItemDocument, Long>

@Document(indexName = "t_source_item", createIndex = true)
data class SourceItemDocument


@Lazy is pretty much your only option, but the only reason for you to not start Elastic would be for some quick local development (can't imagine any other reason) - in that case just mark the not needed beans with some @Profile(!foo) and use foo for local development I would say

Can you please share your code?

@HarshShiyani I've added code that might be relevant.

@JAsgarov Not for my case, local developing just doesn't need Elasticsearch when developing some modules, it doesn't always not need Elasticsearch. The case of using @Profile is to set the value of the annotation createIndex based on Profile, but this should not be possible.
